# Vaadin Flow 14 how to set HttpOnly cookie flag

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

We have a Vaadin Flow 14.x enterprise app and a recent security review highlighted the lack of HttpOnly flag being set with the JSESSIONID cookie.  How do we set this flag with Vaadin Flow 14?  I've searched quite a bit and have not found any references to this.

Our app uses embedded jetty, but that probably doesn't matter in this case as its Vaadin that's setting JSESSIONID from what we can tell.

**SOLUTION**

The solution as described below is to configure embedded jetty to set HttpOnly.  In my case I did this via:

```
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.getSessionHandler().setHttpOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to configure this through Jetty. Vaadin is just using `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` without directly touching any low-level session management details such as cookies.

Comment: So I should somehow add a custom HttpSession class to jetty? Or add some kind of HttpSesssion creation listener? I'm guessing there's some such support to do this in jetty.

Comment: If you've already identified the right setting, then it could be nice to share it in this context so that others wouldn't have to go searching for it.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand it's been edited into the original question, although it's a bit unusual place for answers.